# Potential Problems of Excessively Hard Shaft

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, manufacturing-engineering, solid-mechanics, machine-design

Will there be any issues if we make the shaft too hard?
Hardness being a surface property may prevent surface scratches and wear, could it lead to any problems in general?

Comment: What do you mean  "too hard".? What is the Rockwell or other test result. ?

Comment: "*Hardness being a surface property may prevent surface scratches and wear, could it lead to any problems in general?*" Hardness is not a surface property, but normally you only care about hardness at the surface, hence case hardened shafts exist which helps you retain the toughness of the bulk material underneath.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how deep the surface hardness goes, as follows.

The ideal condition for shafting is when the surface is *hard* (resistant to yield) and the interior is *tough* (large amount of work required to reach failure, usually measured by *Charpy impact*).

Now, what exactly is "toughness"? Broadly speaking, it is the area under the stress-strain curve all the way up to the point of fracture. This represents the total amount of work absorbed by a chunk of material in the process of pulling it apart. Toughness is a good property for a stressed machine element to have- in particular, something like an axle shaft, a U-joint, or a gear.

To maximize the area under the curve requires two things: that the curve be *tall* (high initial yield stress) and *wide* (lots of deformation before neckdown and failure). Note here that a material with a low curve is called "soft" (easy to smoosh) and a very tall curve is "hard" (resistant to being dented). A curve that is really wide represents a material that is "ductile" (easily deformed, like rubber) and a narrow curve represents a material that is "brittle" (fails without plastic deformation, like a piece of ordinary glass).

If the whole shaft is uniformly hard it will not exhibit impact toughness (ability to survive suddenly-applied *shock loads*). If the surface is not hard it will not exhibit optimal *fatigue resistance*.

Comment: Is there a connection between hardness and brittleness, i.e. if a material is hard then it must be brittle and brittle materials have low toughness

Comment: Can you elaborate on the relationship between hardness and toughness, and how hardness affects toughness? I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: @Max, I will try an edit. -NN

Comment: Excessively hard shafts are subject to micro-cracking.

Comment: @Max There is a *tendency*, not a relationship between increased hardness and decreased toughness in materials, because materials are complicated.